# ajax post does not return view data

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ajax post to call controller method `DeviceData()`. It does not return view data.
When I try to debug the code ,values are assigned to `viewBag` both in controller.cs and .cshtml but browser displays no data. Code does not return any error. After ajax call it only shows `patientDDL`.

I need to display "deviceName date  etc.." which I assigned in `viewBag`.

This is my code:

#### `DeviceData.cshtml`

```
@model Hospital.Models.DeviceModel
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="pdf" class="pull-left">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="blue-bgcolor">Patient List : </td>
          <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("FromJson", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty <SelectListItem>()),"select", 
                    new { Class = "form-control", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <table class="table valign-middle">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Device Name</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.deviceName</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DateTime</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.date</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SPO2</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.spo2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PR</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.pr</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "PatinetDDl",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: JSON,
        success: function(result) {
            $(result).each(function() {
                $("#FromJson").append($("<option></option>").val(this.Value).html(this.Text));
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {}
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SelectedIndexChanged() {
      var pid = $("#FromJson").val();
      alert(pid);
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Data/DeviceData',
          type: 'POST',
          datatype: 'json',
          //contentType: 'application/json',
          data: { pid: +pid },
          success: function (result) { },
          error: function () { alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..") },
    });
  }
</script>
```

#### `Datacontroller.cs`

```cs
public JsonResult PatinetDDl()
{
    Common.DBConnect.fnconchk(con);
    DataTable dtpatient = new DataTable();
    string query = "";
    query = "select Preg_id,P_Name from Patient_Reg";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    da.Fill(dtpatient);

    List<SelectListItem> ObjList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dtpatient.Rows)
    {
        ObjList.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = row["P_Name"].ToString(),
            Value = row["Preg_id"].ToString()
        });
    }
    var jsonData = ObjList;
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeviceData()
{
    DeviceModel obj = new DeviceModel();
    return View(obj);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeviceData(string pid)
{
    DeviceModel obj = new DeviceModel();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Common.DBConnect.fnconchk(con);
    if (pid != null)
    {
        string query = "";
        query = " select D_Name,Date_Time,D_Value1 from readings where pid='" + pid;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        da.Fill(dt);
        ViewBag.deviceName = dt.Rows[0]["D_Name"].ToString();
        ViewBag.date = dt.Rows[0]["Date_Time"].ToString();
        ViewBag.spo2 = dt.Rows[0]["D_Value1"].ToString();
        ViewBag.pr = dt.Rows[0]["D_Value2"].ToString();
    }
    return View(obj);
}
```

Comment: In PatientDDL you are returning json and in DeviceData you want to return a view so there is little bit changing in your ajax call datatype: 'html' make json to html to get html response

Comment: @Shahrukh Khan  I tried  .That didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Many things you want to change to get the desire output.

**First**

make a partial view name **_deviceInfo.cshtml**

```
<table class="table valign-middle">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Device Name</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.deviceName</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DateTime</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.date</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SPO2</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.spo2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PR</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.pr</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Second**

Changing in your controller action method

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult DeviceData(string pid)
{
    DeviceModel obj = new DeviceModel();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Common.DBConnect.fnconchk(con);
    if (pid != null)
    {
        string query = "";
        query = " select D_Name,Date_Time,D_Value1 from readings where pid='" + pid;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        da.Fill(dt);
        ViewBag.deviceName = dt.Rows[0]["D_Name"].ToString();
        ViewBag.date = dt.Rows[0]["Date_Time"].ToString();
        ViewBag.spo2 = dt.Rows[0]["D_Value1"].ToString();
        ViewBag.pr = dt.Rows[0]["D_Value2"].ToString();
    }
    return PartialView(obj);
}
```

**Third**

Ajax Method in **DeviceData.cshtml**

```
@model Hospital.Models.DeviceModel
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="pdf" class="pull-left">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="blue-bgcolor">Patient List : </td>
          <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("FromJson", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty <SelectListItem>()),"select", 
                    new { Class = "form-control", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="device-data">
  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "PatinetDDl",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: JSON,
        success: function(result) {
            $(result).each(function() {
                $("#FromJson").append($("<option></option>").val(this.Value).html(this.Text));
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {}
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SelectedIndexChanged() {
      var pid = $("#FromJson").val();
      alert(pid);
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Data/DeviceData',
          type: 'POST',
          datatype: 'html',
          //contentType: 'application/json',
          data: { pid: +pid },
          success: function (result) {
$('#device-data').html(result);
 },
          error: function () { alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..") },
    });
  }
</script>
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you return a view by action result (html) but you have used data type json in your second ajax script.
Edit SelectedIndexChanged like this :

```
function SelectedIndexChanged() {
      var pid = $("#FromJson").val();
      alert(pid);
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Data/DeviceData',
          type: 'POST',
          datatype: 'html',
          //contentType: 'application/json',
          data: { pid: +pid },
          success: function (data) { 
            $('#placeHolder').html(data);
          },
          error: function () { alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..") },
    });
  }
```

Don't forget to add placeHolder element where ever you want to show the DeviceData:

```
<div id="#placeHolder"></div>
```